# Translate controller class variables in zend framework 2

Tags: internationalization, zend-framework2

Let's say I have a controller and I want to define some const variables that hold some messages (eg error messages etc).

Is there a way to make it so they are translated?
An example class is defined bellow:

```
<?php
namespace Test\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AccountController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $testError = 'There was an error while testing some stuff';

    public function testAction(){

        // I know i can use the following approach but I don't want to
        // since I want to use a variable for readability issues.
        // $testError = $this->getTranslator()->translate('There was an error..');

        return new ViewModel();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the translator
     *
     * @return \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator
     */
    public function getTranslator()
    {
        if (!$this->translator) {
            $this->setTranslator($this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator'));
        }
        return $this->translator;
    }

    /**
     * Set the translator
     *
     * @param $translator
     */
    public function setTranslator($translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
}
```

So I want to have the testError translated. I know I can just use the message and translate it via the zend translator without using a variable, but still I want to store it in a variable for readability issues. Any help or other approaches to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a `translations.phtml` file in any directory in your project root and fill it something like that:

```
<?php

// Colors
_('Black');
_('White');
_('Green');
_('Light Green');
_('Blue');
_('Orange');
_('Red');
_('Pink');
```

In poedit, check Catalog Properties > Source keywords list an be sure `_` character is exists. (Alias of the [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) method). In application, use `$this->translate($colorName)` for example.

When poedit scanning your project directory to find the keywords which needs to be translated, `translations.phtml` file will be scanned too.

Another handy approach is using `_` method (gettext alias) to improve code readability. Example:

```
$this->errorMsg = _('There was an error..');
```

But don't forget to set the global [Locale object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php)'s default locale value too when you initialising your translator instance first time in a TranslatorServiceFactory or onBootstrap method of the module:

```
    ...
    $translator = \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator\Translator::factory($config['translator']);
    $locale = 'en_US';
    $translator->setLocale($locale);
    \Locale::setDefault($translator->getLocale());
    return $translator;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you mean:

```
$errorMessage = 'FooBarBazBat";

return new ViewModel(array(
    'error' => $this->getTranslator()->translate($errorMessage)
));
```

would be a way to store the message inside a variable. But i really don't understand where your problem is.

Or do you mean having the translator as variable?

```
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('translate');
$errorMessage = $translator('FooBarBazBat');
```

Comment: I want to store it in a class variable, rather than just a variable in a function.
As in my example, I want the class variable $testError to be translated. Would it work the same way as a local variable?

Comment: Oh geez, yeah, ZF2 doesn't change the native PHP so of course you can do something like `$translator->translate($this->someClassVar)`

Comment: My issue then is that I can't get it to be "read" by poedit, should I manually add it and it will work okay? Sorry for any inconvenience.